# Clarification on "client_id" and "client_secret" values for GCP model configuration

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, typesense

In the given model configuration snippet:

```
"model_config": {
  "model_name": "gcp/embedding-gecko-001",
  "access_token": "your_gcp_access_token",
  "refresh_token": "your_gcp_refresh_token",
  "client_id": "your_gcp_app_client_id", 
  "client_secret": "your_gcp_client_secret",
  "project_id": "your_gcp_project_id"
}
```

Where to obtain or generate for "client_id" and "client_secret" for a GCP (Google Cloud Platform) application?

Additionally, any specific considerations or permissions required for the GCP project in relation to these parameters would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To set up Google OAuth, use the Google Cloud Console GUI.

- Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
- From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
- If the APIs & services page isn't already open, open the console left side menu and select APIs & services.
- On the left, click Credentials.
- Click New Credentials, then select OAuth client ID.
- Select the appropriate application type for your project and enter any additional information required. Application types are described in more detail in the following sections.
- If this is your first time creating a client ID, you can also configure your consent screen by clicking Consent Screen. (The following procedure explains how to set up the Consent screen.) You won't be prompted to configure the consent screen after you do it the first time.
- Click Create client ID

Read the following document to understand the **application type** that you select.

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: Thanks for reply I have followed your guide but it saying  "Invalid client_id, client_secret or refresh_token in `embed.model config'."

Comment: @MuazzemHossain - Edit your question and show the code that is referencing `model_config`. Also, you will only receive access or refresh tokens after a successful authorization process. Show that code as well.

Comment: https://typesense.org/docs/0.25.2/api/vector-search.html#using-gcp-vertex-ai-api

Actually I am trying to configure typesense vector search using GCP Vertex AI API.